# what does scanf specifier "n" count?

Tags: c, scanf

As a part of program I process commands as a series of tokens. So far I´ve got:

```
void exec_this(char* cmd) {
  char token[100] = {0};
  sscanf(cmd, "%s", token)
  if(0 == strcmp(token, "add")) {
    char arg1[100] = {0};
    sscanf(cmd, "%*s%s", arg1);    
    // continue parsing more args...
  }
}
```

The "%*s" is ugly, especially when there are many arguments.

Looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ there is a possible specifier "n" for retrieveing "characters read so far". Not sure what "read" means in this case since there are whitespaces and stuff in the strings not part of the retrieved string; "add foo 42". This is how I want it to work but not sure if it is right:

```
void exec_this(char* cmd) {
  char token[100] = {0};
  int n;
  sscanf(cmd, "%s%n", token, &n);
  if(0 == strcmp(token, "add")) {
    char arg1[100] = {0};
    sscanf(&cmd[n], "%s%n", arg1, &n);
    // continue parsing more args...
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to check the return value from `sscanf` so you know whether the `n` value is valid.  It doesn’t count as a conversion, so make sure there is an assigning conversion specification (or only white space after one) before the `%n` — so you can’t have an undetectable matching failure.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes you are right. I omitted error handling on purpose to keep the examples simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of characters read so far is inclusive of all whitespaces:

```
int a, b, c;
sscanf("     quick  brown       fox jumps", "%*s%n%*s%n%*s%n", &a, &b, &c);
printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
```

The above [prints](https://ideone.com/M7LQBE) `10 17 27`, letting you obtain a position within the buffer at each point of the scan.

This is perfect for your use case, because you can skip the number of characters processed in the first `sscanf` when going into the second `sscanf`. You can use `&cmd[n]` or an equivalent `cmd+n` to skip the initial `n` characters.

Comment: @Andreas Not really, they forgot to say that `n` is not counted among the filled items on the argument list. In a way, this is a meta-information, because it describes the input without coming from the input directly.

Comment: alinsoar's answer made that clear ("n" does not increment assignment count). removed the original comment

Answer (score 1):

The ISO 9899 says at `7.19.6.2p12`:

> > `n` ~~ No  input  is  consumed. The  corresponding  argument  shall  be  a  pointer  to
> >     **signed integer into which is to be written the number of characters read from
> >     the input stream so far by this call to the fscanf function**.  Execution of a
> >     %n directive  does  not  increment  the  assignment  count  returned  at  the
> >     completion of execution of the fscanf function.  No argument is converted,
> >     but one is consumed. If the conversion speciﬁcation includes an assignment-
> >     suppressing character or a ﬁeld width, the behavior is undeﬁned.